# divpd unrecognized opcode x64

Tags: delphi, assembly, freepascal

I have created quite an assembler optimized library for matrix operations which was initially meant for Delphi 2007+.

The code works quite well under Delphi so I wanted to support Freepascal as well and I got quite far until I encountered an assembler syntax error on a line like:

divdp xmm1, [r9 + rax - 112];

Freepascal (actually Lazaraus) reports there an error:
unrecognized opcoded DIVP

I'm a bit puzzled since this is a standard assembler directive...
Anyone knows how I can "teach" Freepascal to understand this type of instruction?

(note I don't want to introduce any db instructions...)

Comment: Is `divdp` a typo? Did you mean `divpd` (Divide Packed Double-Precision Floating-Point Values)?

Comment: The other thing to grasp is that fpc is your compiler. Lazarus is an IDE. You should be clear on the fpc version you use.

Answer (score 10):

Assembly code is always tricky to get running on a new system.

First, Delphi uses Intel x86 assembly syntax, where register names are bare like rax and xmm1; while freepascal by default uses the GNU/AT&T syntax, where operands are listed destination-last, and register names are decorated like %rax and %xmm1.  If you prefer the Intel syntax, you can switch the default syntax by either adding "-Rintel" to the fpc command line, or add the [asmmode intel](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu3.html#x10-90001.2.3) directive to the top of your source code file:

```
{$ASMMODE INTEL}
```

Second, divpd is an SSE2 instruction, so you may need to enable SSE as the compiler's "FPU instruction set".  This seems to be the default on my fpc 2.6.2 64-bit install, but other machines you may need to add the ["-Cfsse3" flag](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/usersu15.html#x38-450005.1.4) to the fpc command line.

Together, this SSE inline assembly works on my freepascal compiler with the default flags.

```
{$ASMMODE INTEL}
Program ssedemo;   
var
  X: int32;

Begin    
 Writeln('Starting SSE now:');

 asm
   MOV EAX,40
   CVTSI2SD XMM1,EAX
   MOV ECX,10
   CVTSI2SD XMM2,ECX

   DIVSD XMM1,XMM2

   CVTSD2SI EAX,XMM1
   MOV X,EAX
 end;

 Writeln(X);

End.
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I already tried the ASMMODE precompiler directive and it seems to work for most of the code...  I also tried to add the -Cfsse3 line in the extrafpc.cfg file in lazarus and enabled it in the project options. Still the same result. My guess is that the opcode combination "xmm, memory" is not recognized... Any hints on that (or where could I add this one?)

Comment: Weird!  `divpd xmm1, [r9 + rax - 112];` works fine for me using fpc 2.6.2 for x86_64, and that's exactly your example with the dp->pd typo corrected.  What version of fpc are you running?  Does `divpd xmm1, xmm2` assemble for you?  How about `divpd xmm1,[rax]`, etc?

Comment: I'm using the latest Lazarus version which seems to be built agains FPC 2.6.4 - at least according to the FPC directoryname in the installation directory....

Comment: I now installed lazaras 1.2.0 which is linked against FPC 2.6.2. Unfortunately the same error is still showing up. I started posting the problem to the Lazarus forum. A big thanks to everyone who tried to help me!